# IR2110 high side switching problem

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

I am working in IR2110 high and low side driver for making H bridge of BLDC motor.

It can be switched low side perfectly but not in high side.

[image]

Comment: Way too little information. Provide oscilligrams.

Comment: I am not sure what is the switching rate, but the bootstrap capacitor should not be too high a value. This cap made of \$C_1\$ and \$C_2\$ in your sketch is usually in the order of 0.1 µF or so. If too high, it just can't be refreshed when \$Q_2\$ turns on and there is no voltage to supply the upper stage. I don't know the operating voltages but I would make sure the bootstrap cap. is around the recommended value and perhaps install a resistance across \$Q_2\$ to provide a permanent low-current dc path to pre-charge the cap. at power on.

Comment: The common confusion about high- and low-side drivers like IR2106 or IR2110... They are not suitable for this task. The main use of these chips is alternate driving high- and low-side switches of the circuits such as half- or full-bridge converters. I recommend you to use N- and P-ch. MOSFET pairs.

Answer (score 1):

IR2110 driver works in high freqency switching mode. It cannot work (with the default schematic) in DC mode, like you want for your BLDC motor. This is because something should charge the bootstrap capacitor C1+C2. In HF switching the first low-side pulse pulls the output down, this reflects on pulling down the C1+C2 negaitve and they are charged through the bootstrap diode D1. If the high-side pulse occurs first it will be skipped until those capacitors are charged (until the next low-side pulse). In most applications this works fine.

For your application I see these options:
1) Get an isolated DC/DC with input 12V and output 12V and connect its output to the bootstrap capacitors. This converter does not need to be regulated, but is necessary to be isolated. Diode D1 is not needed.

2) Do not use this kind of drivers and go for a different schematic where high-side switches are P-channel. (depends on motor's voltage)

3) Get an IC capable of driving a BLDC motor. An example is L298 but you should check for your motor's current and voltage.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is micro controlled, you may want to trigger all low side FETs momentarily to charge the bootstrap capacitors as part of the start routine.